# angular ng-include directive only works on localhost; not in a "regular" windows folder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows

I have this very simple ng-include in Angular. It works when I load it from localhost. It doesn't include the file when I fire it up in a 'regular' folder with the explorer.

My initial thougt was that the file SomeHTML.html couldn't be found. So I gave it a path as well ( ../SomeHTML.html ). It still doesn't work.

Anybody any idea why not?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body >
        <div ng-app="">
            <div ng-include="'SomeHTML.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

SomeHTML.html

```
<h1>I don't want to be excluded</h1>
```

Comment: `<div ng-include="'./SomeHTML.html'"></div>`

Comment: Do not use single quote.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
file protocol and XMLHttpRequest don't mix in some browsers (e.g. chrome)

Longer

- I bet you're using google chrome to test this. Open the console/ developer tools and you'll see the root cause:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///some//path/to/SomeHTML.html. Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
>   chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

- This might be a problem in other browsers as well (IE?)
- Firefox doesn't have this restriction (yet) - so the code will work there

Comment: Spot on Sander. I use Chrome and I tried it as well with IE. No result. But with Firefox it works. Thanks!